# Grails saves datetime as UTC time, but reads it as local server time?

Tags: java, datetime, grails, timezone, grails-2.0

I have the following line in my Grails application to set the default timezone to UTC:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

I have an `Audit` entity with a `dateCreated` field:

```
class Audit {
    Date dateCreated
    String message
}
```

Then I create and save an instance of it:

```
def audit = new Audit(message: "Testing audit message")
```

This will save it to my database correctly as UTC time. However, when I try to read it back:

```
audit = Audit.get(1)
```

The timestamp is read back as local time instead. So if my timezone is +1 UTC and the current local time is **12:34:56 BST**, what will be saved to the database is **11:34:56**, but when I read it back, it becomes **11:34:56 BST**. Does anybody know how to fix this problem so that Grails will read the timestamp back as UTC and convert it accordingly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

in `Bootstrap.groovy`

```
 TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))
```

on `JAVA_OPTS`.

```
-Duser.timezone=UTC
```

Source : [This thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Default-timezone-td2221437.html)

Comment: This should be set default TZ OR -Duser.timezone

Answer (score 2):

In BootStrap.groovy you can also specify the city

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Mexico_City"))
```

Here is a list of the available time zone ids in the TimeZone class, printed as returned by TimeZone.getAvailableIDs().

```
Etc/GMT+12
Etc/GMT+11
MIT
Pacific/Apia
Pacific/Midway
Pacific/Niue
Pacific/Pago_Pago
Pacific/Samoa
US/Samoa
America/Adak
America/Atka
Etc/GMT+10
HST
Pacific/Fakaofo
Pacific/Honolulu
Pacific/Johnston
Pacific/Rarotonga
Pacific/Tahiti
SystemV/HST10
US/Aleutian
US/Hawaii
Pacific/Marquesas
AST
America/Anchorage
America/Juneau
America/Nome
America/Yakutat
Etc/GMT+9
Pacific/Gambier
SystemV/YST9
SystemV/YST9YDT
US/Alaska
America/Dawson
America/Ensenada
America/Los_Angeles
America/Tijuana
America/Vancouver
America/Whitehorse
Canada/Pacific
Canada/Yukon
Etc/GMT+8
Mexico/BajaNorte
PST
PST8PDT
Pacific/Pitcairn
SystemV/PST8
SystemV/PST8PDT
US/Pacific
US/Pacific-New
America/Boise
America/Cambridge_Bay
America/Chihuahua
America/Dawson_Creek
America/Denver
America/Edmonton
America/Hermosillo
America/Inuvik
America/Mazatlan
America/Phoenix
America/Shiprock
America/Yellowknife
Canada/Mountain
Etc/GMT+7
MST
MST7MDT
Mexico/BajaSur
Navajo
PNT
SystemV/MST7
SystemV/MST7MDT
US/Arizona
US/Mountain
America/Belize
America/Cancun
America/Chicago
America/Costa_Rica
America/El_Salvador
America/Guatemala
America/Managua
America/Menominee
America/Merida
America/Mexico_City
America/Monterrey
America/North_Dakota/Center
America/Rainy_River
America/Rankin_Inlet
America/Regina
America/Swift_Current
America/Tegucigalpa
America/Winnipeg
CST
CST6CDT
Canada/Central
Canada/East-Saskatchewan
Canada/Saskatchewan
Chile/EasterIsland
Etc/GMT+6
Mexico/General
Pacific/Easter
Pacific/Galapagos
SystemV/CST6
SystemV/CST6CDT
US/Central
America/Bogota
America/Cayman
America/Detroit
America/Eirunepe
America/Fort_Wayne
America/Grand_Turk
America/Guayaquil
America/Havana
America/Indiana/Indianapolis
America/Indiana/Knox
America/Indiana/Marengo
America/Indiana/Vevay
America/Indianapolis
America/Iqaluit
America/Jamaica
America/Kentucky/Louisville
America/Kentucky/Monticello
America/Knox_IN
America/Lima
America/Louisville
America/Montreal
America/Nassau
America/New_York
America/Nipigon
America/Panama
America/Pangnirtung
America/Port-au-Prince
America/Porto_Acre
America/Rio_Branco
America/Thunder_Bay
America/Toronto
Brazil/Acre
Canada/Eastern
Cuba
EST
EST5EDT
Etc/GMT+5
IET
Jamaica
SystemV/EST5
SystemV/EST5EDT
US/East-Indiana
US/Eastern
US/Indiana-Starke
US/Michigan
America/Anguilla
America/Antigua
America/Aruba
America/Asuncion
America/Barbados
America/Boa_Vista
America/Campo_Grande
America/Caracas
America/Cuiaba
America/Curacao
America/Dominica
America/Glace_Bay
America/Goose_Bay
America/Grenada
America/Guadeloupe
America/Guyana
America/Halifax
America/La_Paz
America/Manaus
America/Martinique
America/Montserrat
America/Port_of_Spain
America/Porto_Velho
America/Puerto_Rico
America/Santiago
America/Santo_Domingo
America/St_Kitts
America/St_Lucia
America/St_Thomas
America/St_Vincent
America/Thule
America/Tortola
America/Virgin
Antarctica/Palmer
Atlantic/Bermuda
Atlantic/Stanley
Brazil/West
Canada/Atlantic
Chile/Continental
Etc/GMT+4
PRT
SystemV/AST4
SystemV/AST4ADT
America/St_Johns
CNT
Canada/Newfoundland
AGT
America/Araguaina
America/Bahia
America/Belem
America/Buenos_Aires
America/Catamarca
America/Cayenne
America/Cordoba
America/Fortaleza
America/Godthab
America/Jujuy
America/Maceio
America/Mendoza
America/Miquelon
America/Montevideo
America/Paramaribo
America/Recife
America/Rosario
America/Sao_Paulo
Antarctica/Rothera
BET
Brazil/East
Etc/GMT+3
America/Noronha
Atlantic/South_Georgia
Brazil/DeNoronha
Etc/GMT+2
America/Scoresbysund
Atlantic/Azores
Atlantic/Cape_Verde
Etc/GMT+1
Africa/Abidjan
Africa/Accra
Africa/Bamako
Africa/Banjul
Africa/Bissau
Africa/Casablanca
Africa/Conakry
Africa/Dakar
Africa/El_Aaiun
Africa/Freetown
Africa/Lome
Africa/Monrovia
Africa/Nouakchott
Africa/Ouagadougou
Africa/Sao_Tome
Africa/Timbuktu
America/Danmarkshavn
Atlantic/Canary
Atlantic/Faeroe
Atlantic/Madeira
Atlantic/Reykjavik
Atlantic/St_Helena
Eire
Etc/GMT
Etc/GMT+0
Etc/GMT-0
Etc/GMT0
Etc/Greenwich
Etc/UCT
Etc/UTC
Etc/Universal
Etc/Zulu
Europe/Belfast
Europe/Dublin
Europe/Lisbon
Europe/London
GB
GB-Eire
GMT
GMT0
Greenwich
Iceland
Portugal
UCT
UTC
Universal
WET
Zulu
Africa/Algiers
Africa/Bangui
Africa/Brazzaville
Africa/Ceuta
Africa/Douala
Africa/Kinshasa
Africa/Lagos
Africa/Libreville
Africa/Luanda
Africa/Malabo
Africa/Ndjamena
Africa/Niamey
Africa/Porto-Novo
Africa/Tunis
Africa/Windhoek
Arctic/Longyearbyen
Atlantic/Jan_Mayen
CET
ECT
Etc/GMT-1
Europe/Amsterdam
Europe/Andorra
Europe/Belgrade
Europe/Berlin
Europe/Bratislava
Europe/Brussels
Europe/Budapest
Europe/Copenhagen
Europe/Gibraltar
Europe/Ljubljana
Europe/Luxembourg
Europe/Madrid
Europe/Malta
Europe/Monaco
Europe/Oslo
Europe/Paris
Europe/Prague
Europe/Rome
Europe/San_Marino
Europe/Sarajevo
Europe/Skopje
Europe/Stockholm
Europe/Tirane
Europe/Vaduz
Europe/Vatican
Europe/Vienna
Europe/Warsaw
Europe/Zagreb
Europe/Zurich
MET
Poland
ART
Africa/Blantyre
Africa/Bujumbura
Africa/Cairo
Africa/Gaborone
Africa/Harare
Africa/Johannesburg
Africa/Kigali
Africa/Lubumbashi
Africa/Lusaka
Africa/Maputo
Africa/Maseru
Africa/Mbabane
Africa/Tripoli
Asia/Amman
Asia/Beirut
Asia/Damascus
Asia/Gaza
Asia/Istanbul
Asia/Jerusalem
Asia/Nicosia
Asia/Tel_Aviv
CAT
EET
Egypt
Etc/GMT-2
Europe/Athens
Europe/Bucharest
Europe/Chisinau
Europe/Helsinki
Europe/Istanbul
Europe/Kaliningrad
Europe/Kiev
Europe/Minsk
Europe/Nicosia
Europe/Riga
Europe/Simferopol
Europe/Sofia
Europe/Tallinn
Europe/Tiraspol
Europe/Uzhgorod
Europe/Vilnius
Europe/Zaporozhye
Israel
Libya
Turkey
Africa/Addis_Ababa
Africa/Asmera
Africa/Dar_es_Salaam
Africa/Djibouti
Africa/Kampala
Africa/Khartoum
Africa/Mogadishu
Africa/Nairobi
Antarctica/Syowa
Asia/Aden
Asia/Baghdad
Asia/Bahrain
Asia/Kuwait
Asia/Qatar
Asia/Riyadh
EAT
Etc/GMT-3
Europe/Moscow
Indian/Antananarivo
Indian/Comoro
Indian/Mayotte
W-SU
Asia/Riyadh87
Asia/Riyadh88
Asia/Riyadh89
Mideast/Riyadh87
Mideast/Riyadh88
Mideast/Riyadh89
Asia/Tehran
Iran
Asia/Aqtau
Asia/Baku
Asia/Dubai
Asia/Muscat
Asia/Oral
Asia/Tbilisi
Asia/Yerevan
Etc/GMT-4
Europe/Samara
Indian/Mahe
Indian/Mauritius
Indian/Reunion
NET
Asia/Kabul
Asia/Aqtobe
Asia/Ashgabat
Asia/Ashkhabad
Asia/Bishkek
Asia/Dushanbe
Asia/Karachi
Asia/Samarkand
Asia/Tashkent
Asia/Yekaterinburg
Etc/GMT-5
Indian/Kerguelen
Indian/Maldives
PLT
Asia/Calcutta
IST
Asia/Katmandu
Antarctica/Mawson
Antarctica/Vostok
Asia/Almaty
Asia/Colombo
Asia/Dacca
Asia/Dhaka
Asia/Novosibirsk
Asia/Omsk
Asia/Qyzylorda
Asia/Thimbu
Asia/Thimphu
BST
Etc/GMT-6
Indian/Chagos
Asia/Rangoon
Indian/Cocos
Antarctica/Davis
Asia/Bangkok
Asia/Hovd
Asia/Jakarta
Asia/Krasnoyarsk
Asia/Phnom_Penh
Asia/Pontianak
Asia/Saigon
Asia/Vientiane
Etc/GMT-7
Indian/Christmas
VST
Antarctica/Casey
Asia/Brunei
Asia/Chongqing
Asia/Chungking
Asia/Harbin
Asia/Hong_Kong
Asia/Irkutsk
Asia/Kashgar
Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
Asia/Kuching
Asia/Macao
Asia/Macau
Asia/Makassar
Asia/Manila
Asia/Shanghai
Asia/Singapore
Asia/Taipei
Asia/Ujung_Pandang
Asia/Ulaanbaatar
Asia/Ulan_Bator
Asia/Urumqi
Australia/Perth
Australia/West
CTT
Etc/GMT-8
Hongkong
PRC
Singapore
Asia/Choibalsan
Asia/Dili
Asia/Jayapura
Asia/Pyongyang
Asia/Seoul
Asia/Tokyo
Asia/Yakutsk
Etc/GMT-9
JST
Japan
Pacific/Palau
ROK
ACT
Australia/Adelaide
Australia/Broken_Hill
Australia/Darwin
Australia/North
Australia/South
Australia/Yancowinna
AET
Antarctica/DumontDUrville
Asia/Sakhalin
Asia/Vladivostok
Australia/ACT
Australia/Brisbane
Australia/Canberra
Australia/Hobart
Australia/Lindeman
Australia/Melbourne
Australia/NSW
Australia/Queensland
Australia/Sydney
Australia/Tasmania
Australia/Victoria
Etc/GMT-10
Pacific/Guam
Pacific/Port_Moresby
Pacific/Saipan
Pacific/Truk
Pacific/Yap
Australia/LHI
Australia/Lord_Howe
Asia/Magadan
Etc/GMT-11
Pacific/Efate
Pacific/Guadalcanal
Pacific/Kosrae
Pacific/Noumea
Pacific/Ponape
SST
Pacific/Norfolk
Antarctica/McMurdo
Antarctica/South_Pole
Asia/Anadyr
Asia/Kamchatka
Etc/GMT-12
Kwajalein
NST
NZ
Pacific/Auckland
Pacific/Fiji
Pacific/Funafuti
Pacific/Kwajalein
Pacific/Majuro
Pacific/Nauru
Pacific/Tarawa
Pacific/Wake
Pacific/Wallis
NZ-CHAT
Pacific/Chatham
Etc/GMT-13
Pacific/Enderbury
Pacific/Tongatapu
Etc/GMT-14
Pacific/Kiritimati
```