# Save a Date to database as UTC

Tags: java, date, grails, jodatime

A user picks a date and a time on a page in my web app (Grails, if that matters). I know the user's time zone (they set it in user preferences). I now want to save that Date to the database as UTC (using Hibernate, if that matters).

So, here is my domain class:

```
class Even {
    Date startTime
}
```

I'm kinda thinking that I want to do this:

```
def beforeInsert() {
    startTime = new DateTime(startTime, user.timeZone).withZone(TimeDateZone.UTC).toDate()
}
```

But the `toDate()` at the end just returns the same `startTime` with which I started with (because Date has no time zone information I think).

**So, how do I get the `Date` the user has provided (taking into consideration their time zone) and persist it to the database as UTC?**

I was thinking about doing something like `new Date() - user.timeZone.rawOffset` but then I have to handle daylight time savings and it just feels very error prone.

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294307/convert-java-date-to-utc-string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12208305/grails-saves-datetime-as-utc-time-but-reads-it-as-local-server-time

Answer (score 0):

There might be a quicker solution, but the standard way of doing this is with a custom Hibernate `UserType`. Here's an example implementation that handles the Hibernate 3.x parts (the interface is slightly different in 4.x but the code will be nearly identical) and leaves the conversion of string -> date and date -> string as an exercise for the reader:

```
package my.package

import java.sql.PreparedStatement
import java.sql.ResultSet
import java.sql.SQLException
import java.sql.Types

import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType

class UtcDateUserType implements UserType {

    def nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, owner) throws SQLException {
        String value = rs.getString(names[0])
        if (value) {
            return utcStringToDate(value)
        }
    }

    void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, value, int index) throws SQLException {
        if (value) {
            st.setString index, dateToUtcString(value)
        }
        else {
            st.setNull index, Types.VARCHAR
        }
    }

    protected Date utcStringToDate(String s) {
        // TODO
    }

    protected String dateToUtcString(Date d) {
        // TODO
    }

    def assemble(Serializable cached, owner) { cached.toString() }
    def deepCopy(value) { value.toString() }
    Serializable disassemble(value) { value.toString() }
    boolean equals(x, y) { x == y }
    int hashCode(x) { x.hashCode() }
    boolean isMutable() { false }
    def replace(original, target, owner) { original }
    Class<String> returnedClass() { String }
    int[] sqlTypes() { [Types.VARCHAR] as int[] }
}
```

Register it in the domain class in the `mapping` block, e.g.

```
import my.package.UtcDateUserType

....

static mapping = {
   startTime type: UtcDateUserType
}
```

This is described [in the docs here](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#customHibernateTypes).